# How to enhance set of images at once?

Tags: images, image-editing

I have a set of images (more than 1000) that are low in quality. (blurry when zoomed) How can I enhance all of them at once , Is there a software for that ? or can I do it with a programming language ?

**Edit**

Im using windows and I want to reduce the blur by sharpening images

Answer (score 2):

Two actual questions here:

- Can I enhance an image that is blurry when zoomed?

  Not really. The reason this happens is that the image has a relatively low resolution compared to how you are trying to use it. While you can apply a sharpening filter, you cannot add detail that doesn't exist.
- Can I enhance lots of images at once?

  Yes, quite easily and there are many tools to do this though you don't specify what Operating System you are using so hard to be specific.

  One tool that works across platforms is [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) but there are many others, some have specific functions such as using [JHead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/) or [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to read and change image metadata.

  [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) is another tool that may do the job (Windows only)

  There is a little more information in the answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/441183/acdsee-alternatives-for-batch-editing-images?rq=1).

Comment: Im using windows and I want to sharpen images , thank you

Comment: ImageMagick will do the job, just don't expect miracles.